# CoreData Fetch Resturns 0 Results on second use of a Predicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hoping you can help with a problem having in a core data app. I've boiled it down to just the essentials:

Here's the psudocode (real code to follow in this post):

```
[run a fetch request] // returns 18 objects
[save context]        // no NSError, returns YES - success
[run a fetch request] // returns 0 objects; request is exactly the same request as previous
```

If I don't save, both fetch requests return 18 objects.

The fetch request is done in a separate method, so I'm sure the request is the same both times. The request uses this NSPredicate:

```
   NSPredicate *predicateFailsAfterSave = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%@ IN games)", self.game]; // where THISGAME is not IN self.games
```

If I change this predicate to something simpler, like "fullName CONTAINS %@", @"Frank", then it works both times, even if I include the save command.  That predicate should return all the Guests that have not been assigned to the self.Game object. It works the first time, then returns 0 if I save.

The model, which consists of two entities:

- "Guest", Entity. 1 Attribute (fullName, String); 1 Relationship (To Many; "games", with an inverse to Game called "guests")
- "Game", Entity. 0 Attributes. 1 Relationship (To Many; "guests", with an inverse to Guest called "games")

The Flow:

1. Guest Objects are created by parsing a text file when the view loads. The "fullName" value is set.

   NSArray *namesArray = // this is an array of strings

   ```
   for (NSString *playerName in namesArray) {
       NSManagedObject *newPlayer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Guest"
                                                                  inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
       [newPlayer setValue:playerName forKey:@"fullName"];
       NSLog(@"Created %@", [newPlayer valueForKey:@"fullName"]);
   }
   ```
2. At the time the Guest Objects are made, the Game object has not been instantiated. (For this entire question, there is no situation where the relationship between Game and Guest will be set.) Then the Game object is created, at which point it has no objects in its Guests relationship:

   -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
       [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   ```
               [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
              selector:@selector(mocChanged:)
           name:NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification
                                                          object:nil];

               _game = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Game"
                                                           inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

               // testing
               [self testFetch];

               /// try save
               NSError *error = nil;
               if ([self.managedObjectContext save:&error] == NO) {
                   NSLog(@"Error: %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
               }

               // re-do fetch
               [self testFetch];
           }

           -(void)mocChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
               NSLog(@"notif: %@", notification.userInfo);
           }
   ```
3. You can see I sent the testFetch message twice, with the "save" being in between them. If I comment-out the save, they both return the same results.  Add the save, and the latter returns 0 objects.  Here's testFetch:

   ```
       -(void)testFetch {
           NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Guest"];
           NSPredicate *testKnownGoodPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fullName CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"wood"];
           NSPredicate *predicateFailsAfterSave = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (%@ IN games)", self.game]; // where THISGAME is not IN self.games

           request.predicate = predicateFailsAfterSave;

           NSError *error = nil;
           NSArray *guestsNotCheckedInArray = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request
                                                                            error:&error] mutableCopy];
           if (guestsNotCheckedInArray == nil) {
               NSLog(@"Error initializing GuestsNotCheckedIn %s: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error.localizedDescription);
           }

           NSLog(@"GuestsNoCheckedIn (game: %p; context:%p): %lu", self.game, self.managedObjectContext, (long)guestsNotCheckedInArray.count);

       }
   ```

The output of the preceding code:

> GuestsNoCheckedIn (game: 0x10b54aeb0; context:0x10b526840): 18
>
> notif: {
>       inserted = "{(\n     (entity: Game; id: 0x10b54af10
>    ; data:
>   {\n    guests =     (\n    );\n})\n)}";
>       managedObjectContext = ""; }
>
> GuestsNoChecked In (game: 0x10b54aeb0; context:0x10b526840): 0

Expected output:

GuestsNoCheckedIn ... : 18 both times.

I've been working from three theories:

1. The relationship is being impacted during Save.
2. There's something wrong in the predicate that causes it to fail a second time.
3. When the objects are fetched, their relationship is being altered unexpectedly.

To assist with testing those theories, I've:

1. Removed the NSManagedObject subclasses from the project. This assures me there is no -awakeFrom* that might be corrupting the relationships.
2. Removed all other Entities from the Model.
3. Registered to receive NSMAnagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification notifications, so I can see if something has changed that I wasn't expecting.
4. I've compared the addresses of the MOC and Game objects to ensure I wasn't accidentally creating another one.

This makes me think the problem is with the predicate, as opposed to with the save. Though I'm at a bit of a loss.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The different behaviour could be caused by the fact that the first fetch request
is executed against objects which are already loaded in the managed object context,
and the second fetch request is translated to a SQLite query.

I am not sure if a Core Data predicate of the form "value IN key" actually works,
so you could replace your predicate with the equivalent:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (ANY games == %@)", self.game]
```

However, 
here seem to be problems with Core Data fetch requests containing "NOT ANY",
so I would try the following one:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(games, $g, $g == %@).@count == 0",
     self.game]
```

Comment: The second predicate worked, the one that uses the Subquery.  The first one, "NOT (ANY..." didn't work, though yourself and another poster both suggested it, so it might be something on my end that blocked it.  The subquery approach is interesting, I've never used that before. I'll hit the documentation to understand that better, but for now, I'm very excited to see it working. Thanks!

Comment: I was indeed having weird problems with "NOT ANY" and this saved me. Just checking, do you happen to have any documentation on that statement or is it empirical? It's iOS 13 and I still had problems so it's funny I haven't seen this elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are misusing the `IN` keyword (by using a name of the `games` relationship rather than an actual collection).
The collection to be used with `IN` keyword must be an array, set or dictionary. At the time the predicate is evaluated, the `games` relationship may not return any valid collection.

A valid use of `IN` would be (per Apple documentation):

```
NSPredicate *inPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"attribute IN %@", aCollection];
```

In this  case, the aCollection object can be clearly declared as a valid collection (array, set, dictionary).
The documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) does not mention that we could use a relationship name instead of predefined collection. Although technically, evaluating a 'to many' relationship would give a set, it may not be seen as a set at the time the predicate is evaluated.

A different way to write the predicate could be

```
NSPredicate *predicateFailsAfterSave = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (ANY games == %@)", self.game];
```